# Questions on To_Date function

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two questions,

1.
Why can't I get **HH24:MI:SS** when using To_date function?

```
select To_date(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE),'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS')
from HPD_Help_Desk;

16-NOV-08

select To_char(fn_adjusted_date(submit_date),'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS')
from HPD_Help_Desk;

16-NOV-08-06:01:10
```

2.
Why am I getting an error when using:

```
To_date(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE),'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS')
```

but changing it works fine when I change it to:

```
To_date(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE),'DD-MM-YY-HH24:MI:SS')
```

To demonstrate:

```
select sysdate from dual;

03-MAR-15

alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

select sysdate from dual;

03-03-2015 11:29:22

select To_date(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE),'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS')
from HPD_Help_Desk;

ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

select To_char(fn_adjusted_date(submit_date),'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS')
from HPD_Help_Desk;

16-NOV-08-06:01:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
Because `to_date()` gives you a date object, and you're leaving it up to your client to decide how to display that as a string; it's likely to be using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings.

Since your `fn_adjusted_date()` function returns a date not a string, **do not** then call `to_date()` on that; you're doing an implicit conversion to a string and then back to a date, both using NLS_DATE_FORMAT, and from how your first query is displayed - as `DD-MON-YY`? - that is losing the time portion anyway. So you're really doing:

```
select to_date(to_char(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE), 'DD-MON-YY'),
  'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS') from HPD_Help_Desk;
```

2.
Because `MON` is the abbreviated month name in your date language. This follows on from the first point; now in the first of those you're doing an implicit `to_char()` of your value using the new NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which specifies the month number with `MM`, but then you try to convert that back to a date with `MON`. So this time you're really doing:

```
select to_date(to_char(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  'DD-MON-YY-HH24:MI:SS') from HPD_Help_Desk;
```

And `11` is not a valid month name. Oracle is quite flexible with date formats when it can be; it can interpret `'NOV'` using the `MM` model even though that doesn't make sense really since it isn't a number, but the meaning is pretty obvious; from your example in a comment:

```
select to_date('16-Nov-2008', 'DD-MM-YY') from dual;

TO_DATE('16-NOV-2008','DD-MM-YY')
---------------------------------
16-NOV-2008 00:00:00
```

It doesn't work the other way though; it can't interpret `11` using `MON`. That flexibility can appear inconsistent, and it sometimes seems to be too forgiving.

In the second query you're doing an explicit `to_char()` with a format model specified, which is the correct way to display a date as a string.

The underlying messages are the same for both: don't call `to_date()` when you already have a date object, don't ever rely on implicit conversion, and don't convert a date to a string while you're still processing it - only if you want it as a string in a specific format in your final result set.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Alex, but still i have one more question.

When i change the session to below, i should get the same error "ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"" right ?, instead its giving me the correct results.

> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-**MON**-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

> select To_date(fn_adjusted_date(SUBMIT_DATE),'DD-**MM**-YY-HH24:MI:SS') from HPD_Help_Desk;
>** O/P : 16-NOV-2008 06:01:10**

Comment: @Subbu - Oracle is quite (I would say *too*) flexible with date formats when it can be; it can interpret 'NOV' using the 'MM' model even though that doesn't make sense really since it isn't a number, but the meaning is pretty obvious. It doesn't work the other way though, it can't interpret '11' using 'MON'. It's also allowing you to use YY with a four-digit year, and is interpreting that correctly too.